# SmartScreen Reputation and singned application

Tags: windows-installer, certificate, code-signing, msdn, smartscreen

So we have our application installer that is signed by our new certificate (standard [not EV]). SmartScreen shows publisher correct but application is still untrusted. So the problem is with application reputation.

Is there any way to build a reputation?

In some old topic i found information that you can use Windows App Certification Kit (WACK) to generate XML file and upload it to https://sysdev.microsoft.com, and after few days SmartScreen will be aware of the digital signature. But it doesn't seem to work anymore, at the moment you need to have Symantec Code Signing Certificate.

Comment: Have you resolved this yet? I currently have the same query!

Comment: Having same issues. Seems that Microsoft likes to cockblock any desktop app that isn't using the new EV certificates. For bootstrapped ISV's this is one more added expense that is out of budget.  If you have a standard cert it takes x number of downloads/installs before you build a trusted reputation - problem is no one will install your code (or even know to click on the 'more info' link) because of the WARNING message.

Answer (score 0):

If it's any help, I can confirm that I have just completed the WACK process today and I actually used a Comodo certificate (standard, not EV). I'm still waiting to see if it gets rid of the SmartScreen warning (since it may take a few days). As far as I can tell, it accepted my signed certificate so I don't think it needs to be Symantec.

One thing I will mention is that the site did ask for URLs for my webpage (home page, support page etc.) and wouldn't let me proceed without completing them. If you have a website, that's no big deal, but if you're doing a personal project and don't have one set up then you may have to make one.